# Call another file in python code

Tags: python, shell, tkinter

I have written the following code to create a gui in python and then using lambda i am calling another file.
This code is showing some indent problem .
*roshan/pre.sh* is the path of shell script from where I am calling another python file.
I want to create multiple buttons like this and using a function I will call a
different shell script.

There should be 5 buttons (named GRAPH1, GRAPH2, GRAPH3, GRAPH4, GRAPH5) and on each button click I wish to load another file where i will put my graphs.

For example, when I click on the GRAPH1 button another file which i have named image1.py will load and will show graphs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter, subprocess

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

    clusterB = Tkinter.Button(self, text ="preprocessing",width=13,font = "Georgia 10 bold")
    clusterB.grid(row=5,sticky=Tkinter.W,padx=3)
    clusterB.config(command = lambda:clusters())

    def clusters():
    process = subprocess.Popen(["roshan/pre.sh"],shell=False,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
        out = process.stdout.readline()
        if out == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        print out

    return
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('Results and Graphs')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what is your question?

Comment: Please edit the question to include this information (and then we can all delete our comments)

Comment: Can you post an error message if there is one?

Comment: @BobMarshall 
currently i am getting this error


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./graph.py", line 61, in <module>
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
  File "./graph.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "./graph.py", line 23, in initialize
    out = process.stdout.readline()
NameError: global name 'process' is not defined

Comment: why are you using `lambda`? It's not related to the problem, but it's unnecessary extra code.

Comment: Your indentation is messed up in the question, is it also messed up in your file? Can you please fix the indentation in the question so we can know exactly what the code is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a shell to open a python file, you can always just import it if it's in the same directory and use it just like a module.

```
import image1
thing = image1.function_in_image1()
```

You can also choose to run it directly by using os.

```
import os
os.system(r"C:\path\to\image1.py")
```

In your example, I found indenting problems. Change this:

```
def clusters():
process = subprocess.Popen(["roshan/pre.sh"],shell=False,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while True:
    out = process.stdout.readline()
    if out == '' and process.poll() is not None:
        break
    print out

return
```

to this:

```
def clusters():
    process = subprocess.Popen(["roshan/pre.sh"],shell=False,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
        out = process.stdout.readline()
        if out == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        print out

    return
```